# All categories are disappeared in my menu?

Tags: category, error, magento-1.7

Now I have a very big problem. All categories disappeared from my menu.

All categories are active. I tried to refresh the cache and reindex all index but it didn't work.

Any idea for my problem ?

Comment: have you install any external extension?

Comment: yes but i uninstall them

Comment: The key question is after what does it happened?

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: Check the Magento error logs, php error logs and any other Apache logs you can find to see if we can get any more info on this

Comment: Can you detail what you have recently changed to trigger this. Something must have changed recently to create the menus to disappear. Check the error log files for clues as to what might have happened. If you can copy the relevant section of the error.log and/or system.log file in here that would help identify the problem. Things in Magento (generally) don't just break on their own without a trigger of some sort.

Comment: Did you clear your cache and re-index? Also try turning off flat catalog

Comment: Please check catalog_category_flat has been being working perfect or not.

Comment: Guys, this issue is still apparent. Occuring for us when updating large categories. So for example, trying to manually save a new url for a category in our admin area. The navigation bar on our site completely disappeared for around an hour and then came back, just on it's own! I would imagine some form of index was running in the background that involved dropping a table and re-filling it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check whether new categories are shown
2. check whether the root category is still attached to the correct store view
3. check the SQL which is used to load the categories for the menu
4. check whether any rewrite for the menu is still there
5. check whether any core hack is still active
6. I think the categories are still in the backend, and in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. Include in navigation menu option.
2. Root category is setup correctly.
3. 3rd extesion.

Comment: all navigations menu option included and root category is setup correctly

Comment: This answer isn't linked to the problem reported. We are experiencing the problem too. See my comment above which details more information in trying to establish the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Manage Catalog** -> Select your category.
There is last option "Include in Navigation Menu" Make it "Yes"

Comment: This answer isn't linked to the problem reported. We are experiencing the problem too. See my comment above which details more information in trying to establish the root cause.